# How to disable onscreenkeyboard in libgdx (android)

Tags: android, libgdx

I have created my own onscreenkeyboard. When i focus to textfield it will automatically popup the keyboard. If i add Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false), to the focusing method the keyboard will show up anyway for a second. Has anyone got a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What class are you using for your textfield? Can you subclass that and override the onFocus (or analogous) method to keep the automatic keyboard popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.html), you should be able to do `setOnScreenKeyboard()` and supply your custom `OnScreenKeyboard` implementation. My guess is that it is trying to call `show()` on both your keyboard and the default keyboard. Setting the keyboard to use will prevent the default from showing up.

Comment: Thanks!I just added tf.setOnscreenKeyboard(new TextField.OnscreenKeyboard() {
            @Override
            public void show(boolean visible) {

            }
        });